# What do the square brackets mean in a bundle source pattern?

Tags: glob, aurelia, minimatch

The `aurelia.json` file has a `bundles.source` property. It appears to use the glob syntax that [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) supports. The out-of-the-box `au new` template, though, includes square brackets around some patterns. E.g.

```
"[**/*.js]"
```

In my experience, square brackets have meant ranges, such as `[a-z]` mapping to `abcdefg...wxyz`. That is also what minimatch respects.

```
> match = require("minimatch");
> match("q", "[a-z]");
true
```

What do square brackets mean to the Aurelia CLI when processing the `bundles.source` property?

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, marking it as "answered" would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brackets actually define whether or not we trace the dependencies of what we find based off the [glob pattern](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer). The double star pattern (`**/*`) is actually what defines the *"search sub folders too"* part of the pattern.
While it's documented in the section for configuring JSPM, it is also applicable for configuring with the CLI. [documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/bundling-jspm/6)

> Our goal is to create a bundle of our application code only. We have to somehow instruct the bundler not to recursively trace the dependencies. Guess what? [*.js] is how we do it.
>
> [*.js] will exclude the dependencies of each module that the glob pattern *.js yields. In the above case it will exclude aurelia-framework, aurelia-fetch-client and so on.

For example, you'll make a pattern like this: `[src/**/*.js]`, you are asking for every *javascript* file in the folder and every sub-folder of `src` without tracing any dependencies. This mean that if module `A` in `src` requires module `B` in `test`, then module `B` *won't* be included because we indicated with the brackets that we're *not* tracing dependencies.
Again, if you took a pattern like this: `src/**/*.js`, you are asking for every *javascript* file in the folder and every sub-folder of `src` *including* any dependencies of those files. This means that if module `A` in `src` requires module `B` in `test`, then module `B` *will be* included because we *are* including dependencies.

It is important to note that this is how *Aurelia* defines its dependencies. While we use glob patterns and minimatching, the bracket syntax (as far as I know) is not part of those libraries, but rather a way for Aurelia to quickly and easily define if we're tracing or not.